# subclassing issue with static constant variable in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have Class A and Class B.

Class B subclasses Class A
Class A has a static constant NSString variable

In a method of Class B I need to use the static constant NSString variable of Class A. What are my options ?

I tried declaring the same thing again, but caused problem (internal inconsistency), tried without using (says, variable undeclared).

Any idea how I can solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you post your code.

Answer (score 8):

Make a class method returning that constant, like this:

```
+(NSString*) constString {
    return myConstString;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can declare static constant strings in the .h file. That way they are public and can be used by other classes that import the header file, including your subclass.

Alternatively, you can declare a reference to the string in your Class B using extern:

```
extern NSString *const MyString;
```

That basically tells the compiler that the value of that string is defined elsewhere in the code and it doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

By "Class A has a static constant NSString variable", I assume you're referring to having something like the following defined in your Class A .m file:

```
static NSString * const MyString = @"MyString";

@implementation ClassA

@end
```

To allow Class A and its subclasses to see the value, you can do something like this:

MDClassAPrivate.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSString * const MDBlahBlahKey = @"MDBlahBlah";
```

MDClassA.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MDClassA : NSObject {

}

@end
```

MDClassA.m:

```
#import "MDClassA.h"
#import "MDClassAPrivate.h"

@implementation MDClassA

@end
```

MDClassB.h:

```
#import "MDClassA.h"

@interface MDClassB : MDClassA {

}

@end
```

MDClassB.m:

```
#import "MDClassB.h"
#import "MDClassAPrivate.h"

@implementation MDClassB

@end
```

By moving the static const variables to a separate file, you can allow any class to import them in the implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution to this problem would be a pseudo-protected method that returns the constant string.

```
// ClassA.m

@interface ClassA ()

- (NSString *)constantString;

@end

@implementation ClassA

- (NSString *)constantString {

    return @"MyConstantString";
}

@end
```

Then following on into your subclass:

```
// ClassB.m

@interface ClassA ()

// This is a method redeclaration to avoid build warnings
- (NSString *)constantString;

@end

@implementation ClassB

- (void)someMethod {

    NSString *theConstantString = [self constantString];

    // do stuff...
}

@end
```

The assumption here is that your constant string really is constant, if you want it to be dynamic you would need to modify this solution slightly, but it can still handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'userDefaults' to set a value that is accessible in the whole application.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:object forKey:@"objectKey"];
```